# Regex to find text inside parenthesis

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have mismatched quotes (single and double) around string literals.

I need to match the quotes to single quotes.

I am trying to replace the following:

```
route('any text can be here and special characters")
```

with:

```
route('any text can be here and special characters')
```

I have tried the following regex:

**Find**

```
route('(.*?)")
```

**Replace**

```
route('(.*?)')
```

But that does not work.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because you can't match a literal `(` character by just trying to match on `(` because that character has special meaning in the regex (for example, as used in the capture portion of your regex for use in the replacement).

In order to match something like that, you need to quote the special characters so that the regex knows you mean to match a literal:

**Find:**

```
route\('(.*?)"\)
```

Comment: This is intresting because I have similar problem with old('something') however `old\('(.*?)'\)` in ST3 not working

Comment: @Sebastian you might want to double check that `Whole Words` and/or `Case Sensitive` are not turned on; either of those will interfere with the match

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Please do as follows. In this case, it supposes that Sublime Text is launched.

1. Push `Ctrl + H`. By this, replace mode is launched.
2. Push `Alt + R`. By this, Regular expression can be used.
3. Import `(route\('.*?)(\")` to `Find What:`.
4. Import `$1\'` to `Replace With:`.
5. Push Replace button or Replace All button.

You can also use `(route\('.*?)(\")(\))` for `Find What:` and `$1\'$3` for `Replace With:`.

### Result :

#### From :

```
route('any text can be here and special characters")
```

#### To :

```
route('any text can be here and special characters')
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.